# Changing the text as we change images

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel

Would any know how I can change the text for the #article-title and #article-author to be dynamic based on the object for when that article image is in the center with the Waterwheel Image Carousel plugin? Right now it only displays the information from the last object. let me know if I need to clarify or make better sense of my question. Also, any tips on how I could better write and structure the code is greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    let articles = [{
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/400x500/?Flowers",
            title: "Article 1",
            author: "Edwards Elric"
        },
        {
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/400x500/?Space",
            title: "Article 2",
            author: "James Pal"
        },
        {
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/400x500/?People",
            title: "Article 3",
            author: "Keven Dorant"
        },

        {
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/400x500/?Cars",
            title: "Article 4",
            author: "Peter Scoot"
        },

        {
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/400x500/?Girls",
            title: "Article 5",
            author: "Alex Blue"
        }
    ]

    articles.forEach(function (article) {
        // console.log(article.author)

        let waterwheel = document.getElementById('waterwheel-carousel');

        let imageHolder = document.createElement("div");
        imageHolder.className = 'char'

        let image = document.createElement('img')
        image.src = article.image;

        imageHolder.appendChild(image)
        waterwheel.appendChild(imageHolder)

    })

    var carousel = $("#waterwheel-carousel").waterwheelCarousel({
        horizon: 200,
        horizonOffset: 0,
        horizonOffsetMultiplier: .7,
        activeClassName: "active",
        separation: 360,
        flankingItems: 1,
        keyboardNav: true,
        edgeFadeEnabled: true,
        // autoPlay: 1300,
        animationEasing: "linear",
        clickedCenter: function ($clickedItem) {
            // $clickedItem is a jQuery wrapped object describing the image that was clicked.

            $(".text").css("display", "block")
        },
        movedToCenter: function ($newCenterItem) {

            $(".text").css("display", "block")


            articles.forEach(function (article) {

                $('#article-title').text(article.title)
                $('#article-author').text(article.author)
            })
        }
    });

    $('#prev').bind('click', function () {
        carousel.prev();
        return false
    });

    $('#next').bind('click', function () {
        carousel.next();
        return false;
    });


});
```

```css
.img-slider {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#waterwheel-carousel {
    clear: both;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 550px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#waterwheel-carousel img {
    cursor: pointer;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.text {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -122.5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25.2%;
    margin: auto;
}

.text a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="img-slider">
        <div id="waterwheel-carousel"></div>
    </div>

    <a href="#" id="prev">Prev</a> |
    <a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <!-- <a href="#" class="article-category">Innovation</a> -->
        <a href="#" id="article-title">The Future as we know it</a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam officia natus harum voluptatem iste?</p>
        <a href="#" id="article-author">By Fritz Kyle</a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://bkosborne.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_brian/js/jquery.waterwheelCarousel.min.js"></script>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `char` is a javascript reserved word, I suggest you change that variable name. See https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: Good point, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the source of a current image and find the article containing the that image.

Then you just update the `#article-title` and `#article-author` accordingly.

Your updated `movedToCenter` function:

```
movedToCenter: function ($newCenterItem) {

  $(".text").css("display", "block")

  // Get current image source
  const currentImageSource = $newCenterItem.attr('src');
  // Find article with a source of a current image
  const currentItem = articles.find(article => article.image === currentImageSource);

  // Set article title and author to a value of a curren item
  $('#article-title').text(currentItem.title)
  $('#article-author').text(currentItem.author)
}
```

And the whole updated snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    let articles = [{
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/400x500/?Flowers",
            title: "Article 1",
            author: "Edwards Elric"
        },
        {
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/400x500/?Space",
            title: "Article 2",
            author: "James Pal"
        },
        {
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/400x500/?People",
            title: "Article 3",
            author: "Keven Dorant"
        },

        {
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/400x500/?Cars",
            title: "Article 4",
            author: "Peter Scoot"
        },

        {
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/400x500/?Girls",
            title: "Article 5",
            author: "Alex Blue"
        }
    ]

    articles.forEach(function (article) {
        // console.log(article.author)

        let waterwheel = document.getElementById('waterwheel-carousel');

        let char = document.createElement("div");
        char.className = 'char'

        let image = document.createElement('img')
        image.src = article.image;

        char.appendChild(image)
        waterwheel.appendChild(char)

    })

    var carousel = $("#waterwheel-carousel").waterwheelCarousel({
        horizon: 200,
        horizonOffset: 0,
        horizonOffsetMultiplier: .7,
        activeClassName: "active",
        separation: 360,
        flankingItems: 1,
        keyboardNav: true,
        edgeFadeEnabled: true,
        // autoPlay: 1300,
        animationEasing: "linear",
        clickedCenter: function ($clickedItem) {
            // $clickedItem is a jQuery wrapped object describing the image that was clicked.

            $(".text").css("display", "block")
        },
        movedToCenter: function ($newCenterItem) {

            $(".text").css("display", "block")

            // Get current image source
            const currentImageSource = $newCenterItem.attr('src');
            // Find article with a source of a current image
            const currentItem = articles.find(article => article.image === currentImageSource);
            
            // Set article title and author to a value of a curren item
            $('#article-title').text(currentItem.title)
            $('#article-author').text(currentItem.author)
        }
    });

    $('#prev').bind('click', function () {
        carousel.prev();
        return false
    });

    $('#next').bind('click', function () {
        carousel.next();
        return false;
    });


});
```

```css
.img-slider {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#waterwheel-carousel {
    clear: both;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 550px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#waterwheel-carousel img {
    cursor: pointer;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.text {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -122.5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25.2%;
    margin: auto;
}

.text a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="img-slider">
        <div id="waterwheel-carousel"></div>
    </div>

    <a href="#" id="prev">Prev</a> |
    <a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <!-- <a href="#" class="article-category">Innovation</a> -->
        <a href="#" id="article-title">The Future as we know it</a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam officia natus harum voluptatem iste?</p>
        <a href="#" id="article-author">By Fritz Kyle</a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://bkosborne.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_brian/js/jquery.waterwheelCarousel.min.js"></script>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Okay noted will do